# How to repeat rows with specific times and modify some variables at the same time?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

The sample dataset is as follows:

| name | Number of days of Annual leave | Date from dd/mm to dd/mm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amy | 3 | 01/10-03/10 |
| Iris | 2 | 04/10-05/10 |

The dataset that I want:

| name | Number of days of Annual leave | Date from dd/mm to dd/mm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amy | 1 | 01/10 |
| Amy | 1 | 02/10 |
| Amy | 1 | 03/10 |
| Iris | 1 | 04/10 |
| Iris | 1 | 05/10 |

I tried the methods from https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-repeat-rows-a-specified-number-of-times/#3_Use_the_VLOOKUP_Function_to_Repeat_Rows_a_Specified_Number_of_Times_in_Excel

But I still couldn't figure out how to modify the row `Date from dd/mm to dd/mm`.

Is there any way to expand the dataset? Please give me some suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your link:
[image: Dates_leave]

You must format Column `I` for dates as required.